# Method to Serialize Objects from appserver to web server without code duplication

Tags: php, serialization

I have a web-app-database 3 tier server setup. Web requests data from app, and app gets its data from the db then processes and returns it to web for display. Standard.

Currently all the data I serialize from app to web gets put into custom defined data structs that the web side then parses for display. In other words, say I have an order that I want to retrieve and send to web. I don't serialize the whole object, but rather build an array with the appropriate data elements while on the app server, then serialize that array over to the web servers.

Now, I am looking into serializing the entire order object over to the web server.

What is the best method you guys have found to serialize objects while maintaining separation of appserver and webserver code? I don't want my webservers having any code which accesses the DB, but I want them to reuse the classes that encapsulate my order and other data as much as possible.

To further refine my question (thanks to Glenn's response), I don't want my webservers to have any of the business logic around say the order class either, that only the appserver needs to know. The objects already use separate serialization to/from the database, and to/from the webservers.

Using the order example, on the appserver, an order should be able to cancel: ie

$order->cancel();

but on the webserver that method should not even be found. It shouldn't simply proxy back (directly) to the appserver order's cancel method, because user action requests should flow through the application's authorization and permissions checking layer.

So how do I get an order object on my webserver that has some (but not all) of the methods and properties of the object on my appserver, with little to no code duplication. One thing I've been thinking is to create a base class with a limited set of properties and methods. It would use an inner class to hold its properties, and I would require all data access to pass in and out of getters and setters. These would in turn call the getters and setters on the inner class.

The web and app servers could then independently extend the base class, and use a custom inner class to hold the properties. Then on the app side for instance, the inner class could be an ORM class extention that can persist data to the DB, and on the web side the inner class could be a simple properties holder class.

But the whole inner class thing seems a little clunky, so I'm still looking for better solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Factor out format specific
  serialization code into separate
  classes using the [Adapter
  pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). Your problem domain
  classes become backing store
  neutral.
- Use relational database specific adapter classes on the app tier to serialize objects to and from the data tier.
- Use HTML specific adapter classes on the web tier to serialize objects to and from the web browser.
- Use XML (or whatever wire protocol friendly format you deem most appropriate) specific adapter classes on both the web and app tiers to serialize the objects between the web tier and the app tier.
- You get extra points if you are clever enough to figure out how to make these adapter classes generic enough such that you don't need a different set of adapter classes per problem domain class.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to serialize the data of your objects, but when they are re-hydrated, they should be so into a different type of object (With limited and/or different functionality)?

You can do this in different ways, depending on what protocol you prefer. For example, you could use SOAP. You should then hydrate the objects into a different class on the client-side, than on the server-side. You could also use PHP's native [serialization](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and either a) Have a different code base on the client (Could get confusing) or b) mock a bit around with the serialized string (Eg. replace the class-name). [A crude example](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#79226) can be found in the comments for the PHP manual.

Comment: yes, For instance, cast the appserver order object to its parent class (call it Order_Base) and then rehydrate on the webserver side as Order_Base, and then maybe pass that into subclass constructor on webserver side to construct the subclass there. All that is a little clunky though..